# Extract the text from the Video data

Tags: python, video-streaming, ocr, opencv

I want to extract the text from the video data. I can extract the text but facing some problems. I am getting repetitive texts from the video. I want to extract the exact text from the whole video. How could I solve my problem?  I am sharing my code.

```
    import cv2
    import os
    import pytesseract
    import numpy as np
    import time
    
       # Mention the installed location of Tesseract-OCR in your system
        pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe' 
        FRAME_RATE = 2
    # Read the video from specified path
        video_data = cv2.VideoCapture(r"jonty.mp4")
        video_length= int(video_data.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) - 1
        fps=int(video_data.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
        pos_frame= int(video_data.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))
        width  = int(video_data.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
        height = int(video_data.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
        frame_time = 0
        frame_count = 0
        print("total_frames: ", video_length)
        print("FRAME_RATE", FRAME_RATE)
        print("fps", fps)
        print("pos_frame", pos_frame)
    
        text_data=[]
    
        while(True):      
            video_data.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, frame_time * 10000)    # move frame to a timestamp
            frame_time += 1/FRAME_RATE
            # reading from frame
            ret,frame = video_data.read()  
            if ret:
             # if video is still left continue creating images
                image = r'\images\frame' + str(frame_count) + '.jpg              
                 # writing the extracted images
                cv2.imwrite(image, frame)                              
                # Apply OCR on the cropped image
            
                text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image,lang='eng+deu+fra')
                #print(text)        
                text_data.append(text)      
                # frame in every 1 second
                frame_count += 1         
            else:
                break                   
        # Release all space and windows once done
        video_data.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: ffmpeg could be of help to you